# Where should generated scripts be placed in the filesystem?

Tags: directory-structure, tmp, fhs

I am writing a piece of software (C++) which generates Python scripts.
Where should these **temporarily** existing scripts be placed in the file system?

I read a couple pages about the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard, but I didn't find any reference to generated scripts.

/usr/bin does not seem to be a good idea as it might be read-only for certain users. My idea would be to place them under /var/run/my_program.

Is that right/ok? Or what is the "right place"?

**Edit:**
The scripts are only used while the creating programs runs. That means they **do not** have to live past a reboot.

Comment: `/var/lib` seems to be one place - that's where dpkg keeps all the maintainer scripts.

Comment: How temporary are they? Should they persist across boots?

Comment: @muru: Thought about that one. But I was thrown off by the description: "State information. Persistent data modified by programs as they run, e.g., databases, packaging system metadata, etc."

Comment: @bdowning: Clarified my question: They don't have to live past a reboot.

Comment: I think they mean "persistent across reboots" by "persistent" (as opposed to stuff in, say `/tmp`). If they don't have to survive a reboot, stick to `/tmp`.

Comment: Please note that, according to FHS 2.3, "`/var/run`
should be unwritable for unprivileged users (root or users running daemons); it is a major
security problem if any user can write in this directory.". I would go for `/tmp` or `/var/tmp` according to persistence needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporary files whose lifetime doesn't exceed that of the program that creates them, and in particular aren't supposed to survive a reboot, go into [`/tmp`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#TMPTEMPORARYFILES). Or rather, the convention is to use the directory indicated by the environment variable `TMPDIR`, and fall back to `/tmp` if it isn't set.

You can execute files in `/tmp`. While a system administrator could mount it without executable permissions, this would be a hardening configuration for a system that only runs specific applications: it is to be expected that preventing execution under `/tmp` would break some applications, and it typically wouldn't improve security anyway.

Keep in mind that this directory is often shared between users, so you need to be careful when creating files there not to accidentally start using an existing file owned by another user. Use the [`mktemp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mktemp) utility or the [`mkstemp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkstemp) function, or better, create a private temporary directory with [`mktemp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mktemp) or [`mkdtemp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkdtemp) and work in that directory.

`/run` or `/var/run` are not appropriate because you may not have the permission to create files there (in fact, you *will* not have the permission to create files there unless granted by the system administrator). They're for system use, not for applications.